# Is there a way to create a dynamic regression model (ARIMAX) with multiple explanatory variables?

Tags: dynamic, linear-regression, forecasting, arima

Is there a way to create a dynamic regression model (ARIMAX) with multiple explanatory variables?
The explanatory variables are introduced into the model with the regression part (xreg()).

```
(Fit <- auto.arima(Oct_Mar[, "ctr"],
                   xreg = Oct_Mar[, "price_purchase"]))`
```

As long as I use a variable it works to create the model.

As soon as I want to use several variables:

```
 (Fit <- auto.arima(Oct_Mar[, "ctr"],
                    xreg = Oct_Mar[, "price_purchase"],
                    xreg = Oct_Mar[, "price_view"],
                    xreg = Oct_Mar[, "price_cart"]))`
```

Error:

```
Error in auto.arima(Oct_Mar[, "ctr"], xreg = Oct_Mar[, "price_purchase"],  : 
  formal argument "xreg" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

When I try it like this:

```
(Fit <- auto.arima(Oct_Mar[, "ctr"],
                   xreg = Oct_Mar[, 2:6])) `
```

Error:

```
Error in auto.arima(Oct_Mar[, "ctr"], xreg = Oct_Mar[, 2:6]) : 
  xreg should be a numeric matrix or a numeric vector
```

All chosen variables should be numeric.

Data Subset:

```
structure(list(date = c("2019.10.01", "2019.10.02", "2019.10.03", 
"2019.10.04", "2019.10.05", "2019.10.06", "2019.10.07", "2019.10.08", 
"2019.10.09", "2019.10.10", "2019.10.11", "2019.10.12", "2019.10.13", 
"2019.10.14", "2019.10.15", "2019.10.16", "2019.10.17", "2019.10.18", 
"2019.10.19", "2019.10.20", "2019.10.21", "2019.10.22", "2019.10.23", 
"2019.10.24", "2019.10.25", "2019.10.26", "2019.10.27", "2019.10.28", 
"2019.10.29", "2019.10.30", "2019.10.31", "2019.11.01", "2019.11.02", 
"2019.11.03", "2019.11.04", "2019.11.05", "2019.11.06", "2019.11.07", 
"2019.11.08", "2019.11.09", "2019.11.10", "2019.11.11", "2019.11.12", 
"2019.11.13", "2019.11.14", "2019.11.15", "2019.11.16", "2019.11.17", 
"2019.11.18", "2019.11.19", "2019.11.20", "2019.11.21", "2019.11.22", 
"2019.11.23", "2019.11.24", "2019.11.25", "2019.11.26", "2019.11.27", 
"2019.11.28", "2019.11.29", "2019.11.30", "2019.12.01", "2019.12.02", 
"2019.12.03", "2019.12.04", "2019.12.05", "2019.12.06", "2019.12.07", 
"2019.12.08", "2019.12.09", "2019.12.10", "2019.12.11", "2019.12.12", 
"2019.12.13", "2019.12.14", "2019.12.15", "2019.12.16", "2019.12.17", 
"2019.12.18", "2019.12.19", "2019.12.20", "2019.12.21", "2019.12.22", 
"2019.12.23", "2019.12.24", "2019.12.25", "2019.12.26", "2019.12.27", 
"2019.12.28", "2019.12.29", "2019.12.30", "2019.12.31", "2020.01.01", 
"2020.01.02", "2020.01.03", "2020.01.04", "2020.01.05", "2020.01.06", 
"2020.01.07", "2020.01.08", "2020.01.09", "2020.01.10", "2020.01.11", 
"2020.01.12", "2020.01.13", "2020.01.14", "2020.01.15", "2020.01.16", 
"2020.01.17", "2020.01.18", "2020.01.19", "2020.01.20", "2020.01.21", 
"2020.01.22", "2020.01.23", "2020.01.24", "2020.01.25", "2020.01.26", 
"2020.01.27", "2020.01.28", "2020.01.29", "2020.01.30", "2020.01.31", 
"2020.02.01", "2020.02.02", "2020.02.03", "2020.02.04", "2020.02.05", 
"2020.02.06", "2020.02.07", "2020.02.08", "2020.02.09", "2020.02.10", 
"2020.02.11", "2020.02.12", "2020.02.13", "2020.02.14", "2020.02.15", 
"2020.02.16", "2020.02.17", "2020.02.18", "2020.02.19", "2020.02.20", 
"2020.02.21", "2020.02.22", "2020.02.23", "2020.02.24", "2020.02.25", 
"2020.02.26", "2020.02.27", "2020.02.28", "2020.02.29", "2020.03.01", 
"2020.03.02", "2020.03.03", "2020.03.04", "2020.03.05", "2020.03.06", 
"2020.03.07", "2020.03.08", "2020.03.09", "2020.03.10", "2020.03.11", 
"2020.03.12", "2020.03.13", "2020.03.14", "2020.03.15", "2020.03.16", 
"2020.03.17", "2020.03.18", "2020.03.19", "2020.03.20", "2020.03.21", 
"2020.03.22", "2020.03.23", "2020.03.24", "2020.03.25", "2020.03.26", 
"2020.03.27", "2020.03.28", "2020.03.29", "2020.03.30", "2020.03.31"
), price_view = c(35.79, 180.16, 437.57, 10.3, 74.26, 79.8, 89.84, 
121.24, 461.95, 142.06, 241.71, 52, 43.24, 41.16, 167.05, 764.06, 
91.64, 189.82, 38.59, 152.64, 86.23, 321.33, 411.83, 256.88, 
352.39, 76.32, 360.11, 123.53, 43.41, 149.38, 14.16, 489.07, 
1661.74, 1253.07, 25.71, 154.42, 990.89, 1645.93, 144.12, 84.43, 
240.25, 148.18, 41.13, 262.56, 168.78, 860.85, 239.31, 372.98, 
165.64, 134.32, 20.7, 43.73, 765.76, 51.48, 599.49, 893.79, 155.29, 
334.37, 46.82, 1814.72, 196.27, 1302.48, 40.16, 1161.68, 381.48, 
184.48, 48.91, 221.11, 434.73, 149.27, 77.22, 882.49, 106.05, 
669.23, 282.86, 179.67, 12.97, 460.24, 38.59, 278.26, 243.76, 
1904.79, 84.93, 32.18, 25.71, 496.54, 29.6, 1466.83, 164.33, 
234.76, 19.95, 308.37, 1130.02, 7.47, 79.8, 65.9, 746.45, 1347.78, 
1270.82, 69.42, 231.41, 195.6, 715.33, 208.47, 720.46, 414.68, 
24.45, 217.82, 434.45, 483.92, 1500.42, 318.15, 339.29, 267.45, 
133.85, 9.03, 11.81, 280.57, 916.74, 58.51, 339.78, 33.98, 263.58, 
19.31, 239.88, 489.07, 84.92, 344.9, 95.24, 99.1, 142.58, 480.58, 
104.74, 14.83, 252, 1039.41, 28.3, 328.97, 341.55, 278.26, 43.73, 
91.35, 102.32, 131.25, 155.15, 77.74, 14.67, 132.63, 1185.36, 
291.13, 1106.59, 849.42, 117.63, 171.32, 167.31, 252.23, 248.14, 
111.15, 257.15, 27.62, 169.86, 101.89, 282.89, 298.57, 86.49, 
196.32, 1415.45, 898.35, 334.6, 17.99, 13.62, 566.27, 60.41, 
36.34, 62.04, 308.81, 32.95, 127.44, 836.57, 221.34, 360.34, 
159.31, 20.57), view = c(1206151, 1152770, 1087372, 1344804, 
1270060, 1262993, 1159265, 1323522, 1301376, 1240347, 1445162, 
1432321, 1583572, 1376274, 1462409, 1443323, 1337174, 1413405, 
1382403, 1443838, 1342668, 1353053, 1318395, 1252747, 1369922, 
1288939, 1330209, 1220710, 1187883, 1169955, 1207854, 1402754, 
1513400, 1524803, 1743304, 1670637, 1644359, 1748812, 1789808, 
1783142, 1845552, 1907417, 1892753, 1920411, 2864410, 5691766, 
5986292, 5759703, 1905351, 1627672, 1598554, 1573101, 1471242, 
1474138, 1500022, 1496128, 1557252, 1547199, 1560191, 1727852, 
1644405, 1706901, 1629904, 1547658, 1468085, 1540157, 1652208, 
1725106, 1724452, 1627222, 1651328, 1605421, 1650612, 1634861, 
1760750, 2167056, 2875847, 2780816, 2665285, 2528244, 2387520, 
2340327, 2471739, 2372930, 2326654, 2322753, 2240514, 2058141, 
2089081, 2474226, 2294820, 1603749, 1427733, 1700904, 1765457, 
1754424, 1738774, 1696188, 1701769, 1585870, 1556542, 1557542, 
1618230, 1645866, 1627433, 1612956, 1555416, 1773179, 1826768, 
2021676, 2104199, 1801073, 1733142, 1593991, 1645225, 1557626, 
1637470, 1721003, 1545472, 1594688, 1565742, 1651606, 1999670, 
2217825, 1985751, 1680034, 1608904, 1620473, 1628906, 1726835, 
1589058, 1714745, 1751044, 1896265, 2429526, 2268487, 1935249, 
1916034, 2239698, 1916650, 1981570, 1948648, 1987134, 1749514, 
1822349, 1830307, 1748590, 1734610, 1798308, 162557, 1000204, 
1257475, 1770064, 2416707, 2477258, 2487470, 2457500, 2210539, 
2377633, 2026050, 2301337, 2218894, 2012789, 1700619, 1481115, 
1562027, 1560348, 1338829, 1244973, 1142989, 1260747, 1316975, 
1387394, 1319559, 1440470, 1451015, 1439649, 1390411, 1336076, 
1369834, 1255626, 1244163, 1283731), price_cart = c(29.51, 1415.48, 
99.86, 358.57, 617.51, 1052.79, 1747.79, 190.56, 128.28, 252.38, 
250.91, 720.48, 33.42, 643, 191.77, 460.11, 408.5, 789.9, 577.94, 
49.36, 380.7, 19.56, 994.86, 756.71, 223.66, 437.33, 1684.28, 
366.16, 968.34, 1683.07, 550.77, 503.09, 29.09, 179.67, 210.62, 
22.66, 131.66, 68.96, 360.06, 494.22, 1023.62, 1569.92, 28.29, 
694.97, 127.05, 37.85, 282.89, 178.9, 913.28, 1022.42, 424.7, 
573.7, 1029.34, 30.12, 20.82, 17.99, 107.53, 41.19, 85.82, 1002.55, 
140.98, 167.03, 231.67, 25.71, 205.64, 30.81, 51.22, 65.9, 7.08, 
308.63, 227.79, 16.22, 7.89, 62.52, 48.88, 586.63, 602.07, 1312.26, 
128.32, 179.9, 849.42, 100.9, 1284.2, 12.84, 128.42, 59.18, 176.99, 
38.02, 48.88, 694.54, 262.3, 1402.84, 1453.18, 3.84, 453.01, 
76.93, 7.04, 865.93, 865.4, 40.75, 1423.07, 1534.66, 679.27, 
11.25, 102.63, 436.3, 853.93, 694.97, 850.47, 477.49, 1234.97, 
10.27, 23.94, 643.23, 89.84, 290.34, 320.99, 6.44, 140.28, 188.89, 
56.88, 1326.31, 194.34, 140.28, 771.96, 140.03, 20.21, 1464.39, 
59.18, 57.92, 1156.81, 50.43, 300.12, 38.1, 832.71, 57.91, 174.5, 
100.36, 248.14, 109.34, 100.7, 242.7, 266.67, 592.01, 242.18, 
22.66, 566.04, 38.61, 812.06, 123.92, 168.6, 172.03, 49.91, 16.73, 
108.04, 347.47, 97.79, 111.15, 514.79, 126.1, 178.87, 870.03, 
529.31, 43.5, 2110.48, 771.94, 15.32, 105.25, 7.14, 312.67, 61.75, 
165.51, 48.37, 643.49, 303.48, 35.78, 154.42, 209.71, 76.69, 
25.46, 1415.45, 123.53, 602.31), cart = c(16658, 17268, 19323, 
43826, 35493, 32145, 18052, 18442, 18432, 18997, 21450, 20691, 
24833, 44821, 49513, 45272, 40368, 40127, 39455, 40533, 36675, 
36945, 36407, 35721, 36800, 34776, 34256, 17838, 17455, 16996, 
16798, 18911, 19350, 20211, 21960, 19231, 19670, 19446, 77319, 
70093, 71585, 75135, 69669, 71613, 170183, 481862, 405584, 426261, 
83117, 72450, 72311, 75530, 70171, 64801, 68099, 71405, 71622, 
71324, 71504, 92345, 81760, 84473, 80869, 70192, 66718, 71048, 
83618, 84231, 80773, 80675, 81420, 78947, 80162, 82360, 86689, 
109721, 183764, 155406, 146906, 137487, 127900, 124577, 127381, 
126700, 124797, 127554, 123966, 120940, 127769, 148663, 148608, 
119062, 57614, 71342, 95608, 80629, 78782, 79099, 77396, 74671, 
72772, 74827, 72221, 73406, 72999, 71182, 70235, 79414, 104791, 
103481, 102597, 94354, 90666, 83642, 83223, 73075, 73582, 73849, 
70067, 71600, 72179, 130757, 208231, 169156, 137970, 116560, 
104701, 102836, 101145, 101605, 90864, 92635, 95114, 100283, 
158447, 131720, 118661, 126405, 132399, 98277, 96270, 95284, 
96886, 89046, 91384, 89585, 83771, 83241, 84151, 6104, 40574, 
48944, 81869, 146953, 135144, 132819, 134255, 131648, 141696, 
122204, 122752, 120927, 112159, 102239, 95998, 97600, 99032, 
79662, 76622, 69585, 73822, 74488, 75621, 69098, 73761, 76429, 
75664, 77671, 77090, 77835, 68888, 69091, 73986), price_purchase = c(130.76, 
419.6, 251.74, 252.88, 64.02, 272.59, 172.72, 88.81, 28.73, 1003.86, 
346.47, 130.48, 29.86, 280.11, 358.57, 385.83, 287.61, 22.95, 
58.08, 854.08, 28.28, 62.91, 994.86, 51.22, 9.01, 77.21, 244.15, 
366.16, 366.8, 213.25, 35.52, 566.3, 35.78, 1106.82, 64.35, 722.18, 
131.66, 166.1, 823.9, 138.23, 334.6, 328.19, 243.51, 488.8, 159.57, 
106.8, 54.03, 27, 308.63, 1022.42, 463.31, 144.66, 44.53, 25.48, 
126.18, 365.52, 133.92, 97.27, 12.84, 1002.55, 107.41, 132.31, 
131.2, 789.57, 230.2, 12.36, 229.86, 1386.91, 154.19, 18.19, 
76.96, 882.49, 191.55, 46.08, 24.17, 102.65, 326.62, 924.06, 
923.73, 88.29, 41.16, 128.42, 326.88, 137.96, 30.68, 108.88, 
181.19, 241.34, 128.32, 137.46, 1279.81, 643.23, 1275.16, 717.245, 
159.33, 745.37, 288.27, 177.26, 168.58, 66.85, 331.51, 437.31, 
643.23, 9.3, 0.85, 436.3, 105.51, 7.7, 79.44, 1321.37, 160.89, 
107.21, 172.25, 514.79, 141.06, 900.64, 153.22, 924.4, 176.34, 
94.98, 162.6, 1326.25, 39.9, 38.15, 2162.22, 180.95, 153.41, 
720.48, 720.48, 15.42, 140.28, 514.02, 720.47, 174.7, 197.69, 
411.08, 741.07, 230.12, 501.89, 109.34, 643.26, 23.17, 242.48, 
1317.36, 69.76, 178.11, 153.55, 32.18, 812.06, 302.2, 153.34, 
172.03, 128.68, 939.54, 108.04, 165.89, 56.63, 43.76, 171.17, 
98.59, 21.95, 280.28, 181.47, 730.01, 159.31, 60.75, 31.15, 1412.39, 
7.14, 942.84, 321.06, 165.51, 284.95, 169.42, 303.48, 224.3, 
416.43, 385.85, 492.08, 334.6, 1415.45, 123.53, 308.55), purchase = c(19307, 
19469, 19255, 27041, 23494, 22171, 21378, 23072, 22748, 21993, 
26224, 25373, 29561, 28405, 26372, 31394, 28318, 25850, 24657, 
25098, 25167, 25385, 24731, 23999, 23929, 22653, 23403, 21112, 
20374, 20817, 20099, 22458, 21864, 22145, 26889, 24875, 25319, 
24863, 25714, 22768, 22878, 24931, 22725, 22548, 22124, 45185.5, 
68247, 185195, 28537, 24967, 24947, 25266, 24187, 22243, 23163, 
24827, 24226, 24443, 24305, 32107, 28178, 28345, 28548, 24358, 
24473, 25469, 27505, 27012, 25766, 26802, 27059, 25906, 26044, 
26712, 26559, 35077, 63796, 51899, 49578, 48212, 46405, 44255, 
44719, 46602, 44917, 44949, 44154, 43081, 45287, 49597, 50729, 
38233, 3574, 13975.5, 24377, 28938, 28427, 28875, 27722, 27510, 
26492, 27481, 26059, 25869, 27525, 26322, 27121, 29614, 35086, 
32884, 32548, 32619, 31698, 30089, 30398, 27579, 26662, 26880, 
27052, 26841, 27403, 27612, 33750, 32536, 32308, 28645, 27652, 
28276, 28533, 28426, 25379, 26027, 46480, 60013, 102117, 83216, 
76048, 72365, 87586, 63260, 36377, 31438, 31258, 29324, 28946, 
29017, 27884, 28063, 27809, 27499, 27490, 26316, 31358, 55087, 
46356, 45228, 44406, 43521, 45501, 40281, 41091, 41681, 39266, 
36268, 34754, 35341, 35943, 28852, 27810, 25186, 25501, 26232, 
25775, 23698, 25314, 25960, 26259, 27487, 26966, 25817, 21294, 
22704, 23997), ctr = c(0.0157890561813006, 0.0166396305077271, 
0.0173986509381537, 0.0194731497951218, 0.0179954394804347, 0.01711863909483, 
0.0181582360570687, 0.0171927115779559, 0.0172358403646591, 0.0174638541971058, 
0.0178806664612045, 0.017462347179514, 0.0183790774089859, 0.0199881077619723, 
0.0174426987635606, 0.021089685240109, 0.0205569049800296, 0.0177842661874661, 
0.0173413941476575, 0.0169081718788632, 0.0182456430344012, 0.0182626162052032, 
0.0182543279386951, 0.0186259961442581, 0.0170104683085926, 0.0171132003490177, 
0.0171517774365777, 0.0170457664943143, 0.016903142521019, 0.0175382134561578, 
0.0164120092891695, 0.0157969704536582, 0.014264557168488, 0.0143332034531726, 
0.0152322825367764, 0.0147200846456646, 0.0152154800186776, 0.0140607309566817, 
0.0137719608789332, 0.0122855439272407, 0.0119334194687182, 0.0125752060979989, 
0.01158007808718, 0.0113191407332442, 0.00729059877222415, 0.00731911608538772, 
0.0106771470535411, 0.029937936916542, 0.0143512493034839, 0.0146854166936255, 
0.0149305898441825, 0.015325442746133, 0.015691446743994, 0.0144534643673336, 
0.0147711815606066, 0.0158382630541111, 0.0148728508159624, 0.015102040564144, 
0.0148955533969277, 0.0176392994824187, 0.0163240478169816, 0.0158230497930639, 
0.0166871934499785, 0.0150557839107457, 0.0159453688844757, 0.0158074236363467, 
0.0158454822084702, 0.0149292254566175, 0.0142730130593139, 0.0156929838274791, 
0.0156162350209032, 0.0153802494466767, 0.0150476029799385, 0.015555365325721, 
0.0143761174252573, 0.0154064275947974, 0.0208510166815324, 0.0176754346231314, 
0.0176296702464377, 0.01808584587117, 0.0184482114318881, 0.0179540460804964, 
0.0172054387638893, 0.0186435592467685, 0.0183226179107802, 0.0183442319676677, 
0.0186738733252132, 0.0197702609494553, 0.0204285359857455, 0.0189093019186096, 
0.0207614056972417, 0.0221922195760301, 0.00240617175649865, 
0.00788575626634226, 0.01309841408011, 0.0157695717780358, 0.0156402333683254, 
0.0162649757475833, 0.0155814665868539, 0.0165668899473124, 0.0162596037350689, 
0.0168350415867981, 0.0154154128099543, 0.0150464847912372, 0.0161870630522126, 
0.0156293605393382, 0.0166831626222356, 0.0159851624182969, 0.0181646017543342, 
0.0154736802975027, 0.0147489845006063, 0.0172093148404027, 0.0173801189598905, 
0.0179353887292393, 0.017586875624838, 0.0169123585500959, 0.0155822266067893, 
0.0149761651657073, 0.0167448758587691, 0.0161082597966258, 0.0167303551270177, 
0.0154917937591837, 0.015286011465188, 0.0136306070303869, 0.0152129210946259, 
0.0159440585908669, 0.0161367409642245, 0.0164079686231546, 0.016492577386447, 
0.0155465861608803, 0.0151072490270382, 0.0144004027929932, 0.0251766100192941, 
0.0300583807652007, 0.0394582941939502, 0.0346703430162482, 0.0370259651104479, 
0.0354306787130485, 0.0369234479028471, 0.0313956783546004, 0.0175071227813499, 
0.0153811379243536, 0.0149988963637585, 0.0159494386911496, 0.0151254119566314, 
0.0151138709885764, 0.0152175253675449, 0.015437458845637, 0.0147726989007463, 
0.163043027137275, 0.0264129334017437, 0.0201436139554002, 0.0169325780144314, 
0.0214876387664511, 0.0177445890793224, 0.0172606914733451, 0.017133563936406, 
0.0185813515317095, 0.0180607614170281, 0.0187505760492009, 0.0169511102933927, 
0.0178137558385877, 0.0184785698285323, 0.0201169476464591, 0.0220364679005246, 
0.0212945438945016, 0.021660499704709, 0.0203399246100257, 0.021042755155702, 
0.0207706911083365, 0.0191080416224264, 0.0188521002714409, 0.0176177277744931, 
0.0170654092407268, 0.0167173964870618, 0.0169957130997929, 0.0173290930652611, 
0.018723068602435, 0.0190819762151085, 0.0178334964691514, 0.0160768402598991, 
0.0172883539665594, 0.0176745227466401)), row.names = c(NA, -183L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error explains, `xreg` should be a numeric matrix, not a data frame. The following works.

```r
Fit <- auto.arima(Oct_Mar[, "ctr"],  xreg = as.matrix(Oct_Mar[, 2:6]))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Your book Forecasting: Principles and Practice (3rd ed) is amazing! I'm using it a lot for my bachelor thesis!